# How to take a pointer address as command line argument in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

I have a C++ code which will take a pointer address as an argument. The code arguments are:

./main 0x7fad529d5000

Now when reading the arguments, this value will be read as a string.

How do I convert the string "0x7fad529d5000" into an address?

Comment: You can use `void*` as the type of the function parameter.

Comment: @JasonLiam the address will be taken as a command-line argument.

Comment: So to boil this all down -- you want to convert a string to an integer?  That's basically what it seems like to me.   The fact that the string is coming from the command-line is not really relevant.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well i need to convert the string to something that can be stored in a pointer as an address. The "something" part is the one that I am unsure about.

Comment: Can you explain why do you want do to so? It is likely that it will  not work even after converting string to pointer.

Comment: A XY problem. This pointer is not valid in the context of your process and even if it is, this is a bad way of IPC.

Comment: @MobiZaman [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @gerum I have another application that creates a shared memory buffer. Now I need to have another application that will take the address to that buffer and write some data to it.

Comment: Unless the OS is flawed, there should be a function that grands access to that pointer anyway.

Comment: @MobiZaman Afaik that will not work. The second program will have to open the shared memory to be able to access the data in it.

Comment: @gerum Won't mmap solve the problem? P.S. since this doesnt seem to be the solution as explained by the XY problem, I guess I should ask about question about how to shared memory between two applications...

Comment: and add insult to injuiry, pointer formats are not portable, so there is no portable way to convert string to pointer. On many platform, pointer value in one process doesn't refer to same _physical_ location as SAME pointer value in different process, unless or even IF shared memory was used beforehand. But shared memory doesn't require use of pointer address, it's accessed differently.

Comment: I agree that something is seriously broken or missing if the OS supports shared memory, and you have to resort to using pointer shenanigans like this to share the memory.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie or it's a simplistic OS like DOS or CP/M, or some rare embedded bootstraps

Comment: Hey everyone, Im pretty sure that its gonna get downvoted as well :D But here is the problem "X": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73631785/how-to-read-and-write-to-shared-memory-in-different-processes

Comment: If you want to communicate a location in the shared memory, use an offset from the start of it. The probability that the processes will access it through the same virtual address is pretty much indistinguishable from zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read a hexadecimal from stdin:

```
uintptr_t x;
std::cin >> std::hex >> x;
```

Read a hexadecimal from string:

```
uintptr_t x;
// assuming you used argc / argv and checked argc > 1
std::istringstream sstr( argv[1] );
sstr >> std::hex >> x;
```

An alternative would be `x = std::stoll( argv[1] );` but there is a cast involved there that I do not quite like (assuming the width of `uintptr_t`).

Converting it to a pointer:

```
void * p = reinterpret_cast<void *>(x);
```

Handle that pointer value with care, because it is unlikely to be valid. (`reinterpret_cast` is something that should scream "danger!" at you.)

Comment: Maybe `uintptr_t x;` instead of `long x;`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Better, yes.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `void*` as shown below:

```
void func( void *param )
{
    //use param here
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    
    std::istringstream ss(argv[1]);
    long int argInt = 0;
    //convert string arg to int arg
    ss >> std::hex >> argInt;

    //call func
    func(reinterpret_cast<void *>(argInt));
}
```

Comment: Does this work without `std::hex`? Also recommend using C++ `reinterpret_cast` instead of C style cast